# Is there a way to get rid of the \n at the end?

Tags: python

Here is what i get when i run it:

[' If your Happy and You Know It Clap Your Hands. \n']
What Artist sung this song?:

***Here is the code:***

```py
quizfile = open("song.txt", "r") #external file for songs

import time

attempt=0 #sets the starting value for attempts
score=0 #sets the starting value for score

print("You should NOT use a capital letter at the start of each word entered or it will be incorrect")
time.sleep(2)

question1 = quizfile.readlines(1)
print(question1)


while attempt < 3: #the user is allowed 3 attempts overall
    user = input("What Artist sung this song?: ")
    if user == ("Baby Bum".lower()):
        print("Correct!")
        score=score+1 #adds additional score to the players total score which is the displayed at the end
        print ("Your Score Is ",score)
        time.sleep(2)
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect!")
        attempt=attempt+1 #adds additional attempts so that the user can only have 3
    if attempt == 3:
        print(input("You have ran out of attempts, press enter"))
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Thank you for playing")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Your total score is ",score) #prints the users overall score
        score = str(score) #makes score a string so that it can print it out
        file = open("score.txt", "a")
        file.write(username+":"+score)
        file.close()
```

I don't know where it comes from, Could someone help me get rid of the \n on the end of the output.

Comment: `question1 = next(quizfile, '').strip()`.

Comment: where would i put that?

Comment: Replace the line that assigns to `question1`.

Comment: if i had other questions then what would i put, just the same?

Comment: Yes - it will just keep getting the next line until there are none left. After that, it will just return an empty string. (NB: this all assumes the question file does not contain any blank lines).

Comment: ah ok thx for that it works perfectly